# Automapper How to devide properties from one object to properties of two objects same type

Tags: automapper

I have one object AllDriversDetails that contains data for two driver: First and Second.

```
public class AllDriversDetails
{
    public string FirstDriverId { get; set; }
    public string FirstDriverName { get; set; }
    public string SecondDriverId { get; set; }
    public string SecondDriverName { get; set; }
}
```

I have to convert AllDriversDetails to ComplexDriversDetails that has two properties of same type

```
public class ComplexDriversDetails
{
   public DriverDetails FirstDriver { get; set; }

   public DriverDetails SecondDriver { get; set; }
}

public class DriverDetails
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to do with automapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be no problem. Try something like this

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<AllDriversDetails, ComplexDriversDetails>()
   .ForMember(m => m.FirstDriver, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DriverDetails  {Id = src.FirstDriverId, Name = FirstDriverName }))
           .ForMember(m => m.SecondDriver , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DriverDetails  {Id = src.SecondDriverId, Name = SecondDriverName }))
```

You can find more information here: http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/

Comment: Daniel, thanks for answer. Actually I'm looking for more "automatic" way without re-coding, but it could be my choice